# Python library for parsing YML files - issue

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, yaml

I start using `yaml` python parser (`import yaml`) but found one issue with values in YML file. Example minimal YML that works good (YML file can be parsed into Python Dictionary):

```
examplePart:
  schedule: 5 * * * *
```

Very similar example YML that trows error:

```
examplePart:
  schedule: * * * * *
```

Error:
`expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found ' '`

Is there a way to fix this issue or are there other Python YML parsers that are better for parsing YML files into Python dictionaries?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - The language is called YAML, not YML. Just wanted to add that information, as my edit was rejected for reasons I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is * is a special character in YAML (see the docs [here](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html)). If you want a string of just asterisks, you need to escape it with quotes, either single or double quotes.

So your YAML becomes:

```
examplePart:
     schedule: '* * * * *'
```

Tested using [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)